# Comparing strings in python which contain dates

Tags: python, string, datetime

I understand when comparing two strings via certain operators like ==, !=, >, <, etc.. python uses the ASCII values of the strings under the hood.

My question is, is it safe to compare the ASCII values of dates rather than converting the object to a datetime object in python?

For instance , u'2017-01-01' > u'2016-12-01' = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that particular format, yes. More generally, any format in which bigger units appear first (e.g. years before months) and in which numbers are always the same length by padding with zeroes on the left is safe.

Comment: Thank you. So would it be safe to compare something like this: '2016-08-24 23:04:50' >= '2017-01-01'?  Which should evaluate to false.

Comment: @CodyFlynn no they should be the same format. For example `'2017-01-01 00:00:00' <= '2017-01-01'` is `False`, which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

with `2016-12-01` (year+zero-padded month+zero-padded day), you've picked a format where lexicographical order is the same as chronological order.

The most important data is first (the year), then the month, and the day. It's not possible that an earlier date comes after another because of that property (the zero padding is very important here)

So in that case, comparing lexicographically is safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some tricky ways, for example:

```
date1 = u'2017-01-01'
date2 = u'2016-12-01'

int(date1.replace('-','')) > int(date2.replace('-',''))
```

**NOTICE**

> YOU MUST USE Directive `%d` for Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
>   and `%m` for Month as a zero-padded decimal number.